# Get all the file names from supporting folder

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, directory

I would like to read the the names of the subfolders inside a folder, which I have placed in the supporting files. Does anybody know how to do this, or have a better idea. I just need to have a folder, where i can put subfolder, which will contain three files each and the get the names of those subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [`[NSFileManager enumeratorAtPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDIED).

In there you'll see sample code that shows how to list the contents of a particular folder.  You can see if it's a folder via [`[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath: isDirectory:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a) and if it's a directory, you can add that to an array or list or whatever you're using to keep track of the subfolders & their names.